# Как вводить штрих-код без Edit-а?

Tags: delphi

В программе если кликну на Edit и потом usb-сканер направляю на товар,в Edit-е записывается штрих-код товара и потом в OnKeyPress выполняется Query1 запрос:

```
Query1.text:='select * from Goods where barcode=:Edit1';
Query1.parambyname('Edit1'). asstring:=Edit1.text;
```

---

```
procedure TForm1.EditBarcodeKeyPress(Sender: TObject; var Key: Char)
begin
    if key=#13 then begin
    keyfield:='barcode';
    keyvalues:=editbarcode.Text;
    options:=[lopartialkey];
    Form1.Query1.Locate(keyfield,keyvalues,options);                                   
    DBGrid1.setfocus;
    EditBarcode.Clear;
end;
```

и в гриде курсор переходит на этот товар, но как сделать тоже самое без Edit-а? то есть просканировал и сразу переход на этот товар? Или  без компонента работы с бар-кодом это невозможно?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Чисто теоретически, требует практической проверки.**
Основное отличие сканера штрихкодов от клавиатуры - это очень быстрый ввод символов. Поэтому можно выставить у формы свойство `KeyPreview := True`, и написать обработчик, который будет запоминать в буфере последние **N** введённых символов, где **N** - максимальная длина штрихкода, с которыми вы работаете. При этом логика работы следующая:

1. Если мы считали символ, которого не может быть в штрих коде - сброс процедуры, отмена таймера;
2. Если считали допустимый символ - запускаем (обнуляем) короткий таймер со временем срабатывания **2T**, где **T** - максимальный временной интервал между символами кода, поступающими со сканера (можно определить экспериментально);
3. Добавляем символ в буфер;
4. Пока таймер не сработал - накапливаем символы в буфере;
5. При срабатывании таймера отключаем его и смотрим на длину буфера: если она укладывается в длину штрихкода, то предлагаем пользователю подтвердить корректность ввода штрихкода. Если же в буфере всего несколько символов, то значит это просто ручной ввод и можно просто дропнуть его содержимое.

Из недостатков, навскидку:

1. Могут быть ложные срабатывания, если кто-то с хорошим навыком быстрой печати вводит куда-то большое число;
2. Цифры со сканера пойдут дальше в приложение (подавлять их нельзя, вдруг это ручной ввод) и могут вызвать незапланированные эффекты (имхо решаемо);

PS: Если сканер сам передаёт **#13** после считывания штрихкода, то даже таймер не нужен, при нажатии клавиши проверять время, прошедшее с последнего нажатия и если оно больше **2T** - очищать буфер, а штрихкод обрабатывать при получении **#13** в течениии допустимого интервала.

**Вариант 2:**

Сделать "горячую клавишу", например **Ctrl**. Т.е. при нажатом **Ctrl** приложение автоматически считает, что ввод идёт со сканера, а не с клавиатуры, и может либо автоматом фокусить нужный Edit (возвращая фокус обратно, при отпускании клавиши), либо накапливать введённые символы, как в первом варианте.

Comment: Alekcvp, в варианте2 один раз нажал на, например, ctrl и выписал один товар, потом надо буфер очистить и снова нажимаю на ctrl, правильно я вас понял? 
Если так, тогда какая разница для юзера- каждый раз фокусить маусом Edit или на ctrl  нажимать?

Comment: Ну, то что контрол нажать быстрее, чем ткнуть мышой в определенное место экрана?.. Буфер можно очищать по отпусканию. Но это всё просто заготовки для решения, требуют доработки напильником. У меня нет сканера, так что допилить не могу.

Answer (score 4):

Обычно сканеры штрихкода просто эмулируют ввод распознанного штрихкода с клавиатуры. Именно поэтому требуется фокус на поле ввода - если он будет где-то ещё, то именно в это "где-то ещё" и выполнятся эмулируемые нажатия клавиш (и хорошо, если при этом не произойдёт ничего незапланированного - а ведь может...).
Хотите избавиться от Edit? используйте любой другой контрол, понимающий ввод текста в него с клавиатуры.

Но разумнее просто найти способ сделать этот Edit неотображаемым (нулевой размер, расположение за гридом и т.п. - смотря что из этого возможно в рамках языка).

Comment: Клавиатурный ввод может обрабатывать и грид и сама форма. Но не сойдет ли пользователь с ума, если при нажатии цифр на клавиатуре форма начнет что-то искать в гриде?

Comment: Проблема в том, что и грид, и форма просто обрабатывают нажатия клавиш (что реальные, что эмулируемые) "поштучно". Так что для приёма кода придётся заводить статический буфер для накопления кода. А ещё отделять нажатия от сканера от всех прочих. В то время как Edit сам накапливает "последствия" их нажатия, если обработчиками не задано иное.

Comment: Я это прекрасно понимаю. Ответ на вопрос автора - можно, но это будет не разумно.

Comment: Зависит от того, позволяет ли драйвер сканера определить факт считывания кода. Может, там есть такая фича? Не, оно, конечно вряд ли, нафига бы оно надо - но вдруг...

Comment: Некоторые сканеры можно перенастроить на работу в режиме эмуляции COM-порта, а не клавиатуры.

Comment: @Akina, сделать  EditBarcode неотображаемым, конечно, можно, но я  не понял вот что: как "заставить" сканер перепригнуть  от другого контрола, например от грида или другого Edit-а на EditBarcode без предыдушего клика на него?

Comment: А вот на эти вопросы надо искать ответы в документации на сканер. И не факт, что они там есть. Потому как программа не может самостоятельно проинтуичить, что оператор взял в руки сканер и собирается нажать на кнопку.